# Ruby on Rails: how to change the language of error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n

Now I want to use `error.full_messages` to display the error messages. But it's default language is English. I want to show other language's error message. How can I do that? Or I have to self define something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to error messages for your models, you can internationalize your error messages in your locale yaml files using the `activerecord.errors` key.  For example:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: can't be blank
            email:
              blank: can't be blank
              invalid: is invalid
            password:
              too_short: is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
```

See [section 5.1.1 of the Rails i18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) for more details on i18n-izing error messages.